# How do I use ssh ProxyCommand to connect to remote MySQL server behind bastion host?

Tags: networking, ssh, mysql, port-forwarding

Three machines are involved here.

1. Localhost where I do my development. AKA laptop.
2. Bastion host where you must connect first. AKA jump.
3. MySQL server where I want to connect to. AKA DB.

My ssh public key is in /home/myusername/.ssh/authorized_keys on jump.

My ~/.ssh/config has this:

```
Host jump
    HostName jump.domain.com
    User myusername
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myprivatekey
```

I can `ssh jump` and get onto jump fine.

What ssh command do I need to run in terminal on Laptop in order to be able to connect from Laptop to DB via

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3308
```

I need an SSH tunnel and a port forwarding, but I have yet to get the syntax correct. I want to use 3308 for production DB and 3307 for staging DB and am running local MySQL DB on 3306, which is why port forwarding to non-standard mysql ports.

Answer (score 1):

The command is `ssh -fL <mysql db port>:<mysql server url>:<mysql db port> <username>@<bastian url> '<remote command>'`.

[source](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh)

Comment: Do you have extra sources to corroborate your response?  It looks a little too simple to be that easy a retort to this question.  I'm not calling you "wrong".  I'm just skeptical.

Comment: I am pretty sure -t (force pseudo-tty) is not required for a tunnel to a MySQL server, and -f is required to run a remote command.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up using:

```
ssh -f -L3307:staging.mysql-server.com:3306 jump sleep 10000000
ssh -f -L3308:production.mysql-server.com:3306 jump sleep 10000000
```

which is from http://csce.uark.edu/~kal/info/private/ssh/ch09_02.htm sec 9.2.6

Note: Contrary to the question I asked, no proxyCommand is needed, just the right combination of ssh command line options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following .ssh/config assuming you connect from machine A to C, through machine B

```
Host B
  User username_on_b
  Hostname ip_of_b
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key_for_b

Host C
  User username_on_c
  Hostname ip_of_c
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key_for_c
  Localforward 3308 ip_of_your_sql_server:3306
  Proxyjump B
  # or old-fashion
  # Proxycommand ssh B nc %h %p
```

Then you simply type from A :

`ssh C`

Then from A, you can

```
mysql -P 3308 -H localhost
```

Comment: This assumes that the user needs to log into Host C to access MySQL there, right? But what OP asked is how to open a local port to jump through B directly to the MySQL port on the private host. If you just remove `User` and `IdentityFile`, this doesn't work. In that case, is ProxyCommand required?

Comment: It works as is. ip_of_your_sql_server can be 127.0.0.1 or external ip. Then you use either Proxyjump or Proxycommand, not both. You could also put he localforward in Host B block, but in the case, you need B to be allowed to contact C on its external IP port 3306, but there are security concerns and network admins wouldn't like that. Neither Security.
If flow is opened, then no need to ssh to C. To B shall be enough.